# Is there a way to disable EXPECT_* and ASSERT_* but not the full test of the googletest framework?

Tags: c++, googletest

Our tests are used in order to test our code using the classic googletest framework utilities (like `EXPECT_*` and `ASSERT_*`). But we also use those binaries for our leak checking through valgrind.

Our processes can be heavy and to avoid taking too much time we can limit the amount of tested data. But some tests are failing due to that limitations as it influences our mean and max errors tested in `EXPECT_*` and `ASSERT_*`.

Is there a simple way to disable the tests the `EXPECT_*` and `ASSERT_*` macros are doing but not the full tests we have?

Comment: Undefine them and redefine them with empty bodies?

Comment: I tell if we are in valgrind mode using command line options. I cannot use definitions to redefine everything as I would like. I didn't find any way to do that through command line options, that's why I asked here.

Comment: Well then add a flag to tell your tests that they are in "Valgrind mode", and use an `if` check around all tests?

Comment: We roughly have more that 60 files containing several `TEST` macro calls ^^ It would be faster to change that command line option to an exported variable and do the redefine method. I just think it's too dirty and I wanted to know if there were some other way to do what I would like.

Comment: Have you looked at the macros themselves to see what they actually do?  Then (maybe, just maybe) you can find a way. (Disclaimer: I know absolutely nothing about the googletest framework, I'm just tossing a pebble into the pond).

Comment: @baptiste Redefining the macros during compile time (using a flag for valgrind mode) is the least intrusive way I think. Another (much worse) alternative would be to replace `gtest.h` with an "empty macro version" when compiling the tests for the valgrind observations.